# drupal_add_js to Search module

Tags: 6

I'm trying to add some custom JS to the search module in Drupal 6. I've added all of my custom JS through template.php via `THEME_preprocess_node()`

How can I add JS to the search module (without hacking the search module) via template.php in my theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `THEME_preprocess_search_block_form` to add `drupal_add_js` calls for the required javascript.

Comment: Tried it, no dice. `function framework_preprocess_search_block_form(&$variables) {
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'framework').'/js/search.js', 'theme');
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'framework').'/js/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js', 'theme');
}`

Comment: Do you have more detail about what you're trying to do? When you say "search module" what do you mean exactly? The above suggestion is for the form, but if you're talking about something different, i.e. the results you may need a different preprocess.

Comment: To be honest I really just want to be able to add a custom JS script to "/search"

Comment: Maybe just use hook_preprocess_page then and just use arg() to get your current page.

Comment: perfect, that did the job